# Save file as csv, keeps coming up as .xlsx

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export-to-csv, file-format

I am trying to output a copy of a workbook as a CSV File. I have the code below but on saving it comes up in file type as Excel workbook.

```
Sub SAVE_CSV()

Dim FileName As String
FileName = "CSV Import File"

Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With fPth
    .InitialFileName = FileName
    .Title = "Save Your Import File"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    If .Show <> 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=.SelectedItems(1) & "*.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Try taking out the `*` in `*.csv`? Also make sure the fileName is an acceptable one, and `.SelectedItems(1)` doesn't have illegal characters.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks for the comments! On changing both things my save as dialogue box still comes up with the save as file type = Excel Workbook. Strangely though the .csv extension isn't appearing in the filename input box with the title

Comment: Right before the `.SaveAs` line, add `Debug.Print .SelectedItems(1) & ".csv"`.  Is the output a legitimate path and file name?

Answer (score 1):

You know the name you want to save it as, so maybe it's just a case of selecting the right folder:

```
Sub SAVE_CSV()

    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = "CSV Import File Again"

    Dim fPth As Object
    Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With fPth
      .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\Testing\Documents\Can be deleted\" 'Change as required.
      .Title = "Save Your Import File"
      .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList

      If .Show <> 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=.SelectedItems(1) & "\" & FileName & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
          End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace with:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=.SelectedItems(1) & ".csv"
```

Follow the below logic:

1. Path - Directory
2. "\"
3. File Name
4. File type - .csv